# Trigger Design Question

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

**A bit of context:**

Our company sells vacation rentals and has over 60 properties. When a customer chooses a property, it is stored in a look-up field called `Lead.Property__c`. They will also choose their `Lead.Arrival_Date__c` and `Lead.Departure_Date__c`.

I have a script which determines availability, and also calculates the `Lead.Rate_Total__c` for that property. Rates differ on a daily basis, so we have a calendar sObject called `Property_Rates__c`. This means that each `Property__c` has 365 associated `Property_Rate__c` records per year. These records store the `Property_Rate__c.Date__c`, `Property_Rate_c.Rate__c`, and availability status (`Property_Rate__c.Status__c`)

I am now building a extension to the script. If a property is **not** available, it will now re-populate `Lead.Property__c` with a similar property that **is** available.

So far the extended script can handle a single similar property, and insert it into `Lead.Property__c`. My trouble is handling several similar properties. We have decided that the winning property should be the one with the **lowest** `Lead.Rate_Total__c`. That means the combined `Property_Rate__c.Rate__c` for every `Property_Rate__c` record between the `Lead.Arrival_Date__c` and `Lead.Departure_Date__c`.

**My Question:**

My question is one of design. What would be the best way to:

1. Query my valid properties. (Properties that have made the cut)
2. Query each valid Property's Rate Total (Combined `Property_Rate__c.Rate__c` total between `Lead.Arrival_Date__c` and `Lead.Departure_Date__c`)
3. Determine which Property has the **lowest** combined Rate Total.
4. Update `Lead.Property__c` with the winning property, and `Lead.Rate_Total__c` with the winning `Rate_Total__c`.

If anyone could provide any insight on how to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Look into Aggregate Queries - Group By Rollup and Group By Cube. That may get you the detailed information for the Property_Rates by Property for a given time period

Comment: @Eric I will take a look at this. I already have a method of calculating the rates for an individual property. My problem relates to the summarization of Property_Rates__c.Rates for a list of different properties, and then having the ability to MAP the Properties to the Total Rates.

Comment: Which is exactly what the group by rollup and cube does.....

Comment: I've looked it up and attempted a solution, but I must be missing something here. Could you provide an example based on my problem for me to reference? @Eric

Comment: How about you provide an example of what you tried, the results, and why it is not correct, then the great people here can help you better

Comment: I feel like I need some kind of advanced Map in order to handle a Property, Date, Rate_Total relationship, and I'm not sure how to do that. I would post the Trigger code that I have, but its currently 200 lines long, and I thought my question would appeal to more people in plain english. @Eric I don't understand how to use the Aggregate function to achieve this. I asked for your help on a sample so I could learn how to use it in an applicable way.

Comment: I thought you said you attempted a solution using the aggregate query...It is not easy to write an aggregate query like this without a complete understanding of your object model. Which is why it is requested that you attempt it, post what you have done along with the results and specifically what you are missing in order to make it a solution....

Comment: Yes I attempted to populate a standard aggregate function that I found in SF apex documentation with values that are relevant to my problem. But because I am new to Apex, the standard definition isn't enough for me to grasp the concept in action. And I don't see how it is a solution to my problem. It seems like it is more for rolling up totals, as opposed to Mapping a relationship between 3 sets of values. This is why I asked for you to provide an example. @Eric

Comment: Then maybe just a standard aggregate query using the Property__c as a group with a sum on the rate for the given range...